# Laravel Migrate creating duplicate foreign key names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
Schema::create('a', function(Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->bigInteger('id');
  $table->primary('id');
});

Schema::create('b', function(Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->bigInteger('id');
  $table->bigInteger('a_id');
  $table->foreign('a_id')->references('id')->on('a');
});

Schema::create('c', function(Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->bigInteger('id');
  $table->bigInteger('a_id');
  $table->foreign('a_id')->references('id')->on('a'); 
});
```

Running this with `php artisan migrate` on this gives me a

```
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint.
```

It seems that migrate creates a constraint on b called **A_ID_PK**, then it tries to create a constrain on c called **A_ID_PK** and errors since there are 2 **A_ID_PK** constraints on the A.id. Am I correct, and if so is there a solution?

Comment: Your above code creates 2 distinct constraints: `b_a_id_foreign` on table b and `c_a_id_foreign` on table c in laravel 5.3. You can always check the sql code executed before running the migrate: `php artisan migrate --pretend`

Comment: @ChrisRogers I am not getting any errors running this....

Answer (score 0):

From the error utility, *ORA-02264* error means `ORA-02264: Name already used by an existing constraint`.

And the definition is that specified constraint name has to be unique. So the solution is specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.

**Problem and workaround**
Not sure but the problem is that while the table may have not been created, the `constraint_name` might be exists in the `dba_constraints` view. You can check this like:

```
select
   table_name
from
   dba_constraints
where constraint_name = upper ('A_ID_PK');
```

If you do not have already used this `constraint_name` for other table.

**Your solution is either of the below:**
Use another constraint name, that unique to the table.
Make sure that this constraint name exists for `a` table.